# call a python script from a different path and change path

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have a python script:
**my_script.py** 
that I want to call from another script **main.py** in a different directory.

I am doing this like so:

**/home/path/to/my/main/script/main.py**

```
import subprocess

def call_script():
    path_to_python = '/home/path/to/another/script/my_script.py'
    subprocess.call(["python", path_to_python])
```

**/home/path/to/another/script/my_script.py**

```
do_some_work('log_files/logs.log')
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1037, in _open
return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/path/to/my/main/script/log_files/logs.log'
```

I see that the script getting called is using the path from the original scripts location as its base path.
How can I get the **my_script.py** to use its own path?
I do not want to open a new shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an `os.chdir()` inside your `my_script.py`

`CWD` (the current working directory) in inherited from the parent process. So, since you are running your script from the location of the main script, the CWD for your child process is still set to `/path/to/main.py`

If you do a `os.chdir('/path/to/my_script.py')` your `CWD` is changed to the directory of `my_script.py`.

Or, equivalently, you can use an absolute path to the log file in your script as well.

Comment: Is there a way to pass this in as a paramater when I call subprocess.call() ? as my_script.py is called from other scripts also (From within its same directory)

Comment: Since you know the absolute path to your script in main, you can pass that to your script itself. Then do some path manipulation to get the basepath.

Comment: I passed in cwd='/home/path/to/another/script/' to subprocess.call and now my other script executes correctly.

Comment: I see that the shell now changes and stays at the directory I passed in as 'cwd'.  Is there a way I can spawn the other script as a new stand alone process?

Comment: Not sure I understand, the cwd should only change for the Subprocess. Is that not happening?

Answer (score 1):

use the `cwd` function parameter:

```
path_to_python = '/home/path/to/another/script/my_script.py'
subprocess.call("python", cwd=path_to_python)
```

more info on the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call).